# I need help figuring out why this 'if' statement wont work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a simple rgb game using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript (learning).

What I want to happen is when you click a color, it displays "correct" or "wrong", with the static value of `colors[3]` as the correct one. I've tested multiple things and I think it has something to do with numbers vs. strings or relating but I have no idea. When you click on a color they are all alert "wrong" instead of when you click on the correct color, in this case color[3] (cyan), it is supposed to display "correct".

Thanks.

```js
var colors = [
    "rgb(255,0,0)",
    "rgb(255,255,0)",
    "rgb(0,255,0)",
    "rgb(0,255,255)",
    "rgb(0,0,255)",
    "rgb(255,0,255)"
]

var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
var pickedColor = colors[3];
console.log(pickedColor);
var colorDisplay = document.querySelector("#colorDisplay");

colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;

for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++){
    squares[i].style.background = colors[i];

    squares[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
      var clickedColor = this.style.background;

      if(clickedColor === pickedColor){
        alert("correct");
      } else {
        alert("wrong");
      }
    });
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #232323;
}
.square {
    width: 30%;
    background: purple;
    padding-bottom: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin: 1.66%;
}
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 600px;
}
h1 {
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Color Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="colorGame.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>The Great <span id="colorDisplay">RGB</span> Color Game</h1>
    <div id="container">

        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>
        <div class="square"></div>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="colorGame.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to stack! When you say something is not working, let us know what is actually not working. What behaviour is happening that is not supposed to? Are you getting errors in the console?

Comment: I'll add it to the beginning. Basically when you click on a color they are all alert "wrong" instead of when you click on the correct color, in this case color[3] (cyan), it is supposed to display "correct". No errors in the console.

Comment: Do a console output of both `clickedcolor` and `pickedcolor` and see what the difference is

Comment: You are comparing the hex color with rgb color. First, convert your rgb to hex. Then compare them. And use == instead of ===

Comment: picked color returns rgb(0,255,255). but clickedColor is undefined. Would it not define after you click it as i define it in the loop?

Comment: Mojtaba, when the loop runs, it changes each square background color to the rgb value from colors[]. I believe it is comparing rgb values to rgb values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I have figured out, it's just an issue with the formatting of the value strings. `pickedColor` had spaces between the rgb values.

```
var colors = [
    "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
    "rgb(255, 255, 0)",
    "rgb(0, 255, 0)",
    "rgb(0, 255, 255)",
    "rgb(0, 0, 255)",
    "rgb(255, 0, 255)"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing 2 strings wich clickedColor has white spaces and pickedColor dont. Or put spaces in pickedColor or remove white spaces in clickedColor like:

```
var colors = [
    "rgb(255,0,0)",
    "rgb(255,255,0)",
    "rgb(0,255,0)",
    "rgb(0,255,255)",
    "rgb(0,0,255)",
    "rgb(255,0,255)"
]

var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
var pickedColor = colors[3];
console.log(pickedColor);
var colorDisplay = document.querySelector("#colorDisplay");

colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;

for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++){
    squares[i].style.background = colors[i];

    squares[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
      var clickedColor = this.style.background;

      if(clickedColor.replace(/ /g,'') === pickedColor){
        alert("correct");
      } else {
        alert("wrong");
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about the format of the rgb specifications.

Answer (score 1):

```
var colors = [
    "rgb(255, 0, 0)",
    "rgb(255, 255, 0)",
    "rgb(0, 255, 0)",
    "rgb(0, 255, 255)",
    "rgb(0, 0, 255)",
    "rgb(255, 0, 255)"
]
```

Use this and you will be good to go. There are extra spaces in the output you get from this.background.style.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about the format of the rgb specifications.

Answer (score 1):

This game does not work properly because of how you do your comparison. Browsers have many quirks, and one of them is how they interpret properties.

For instance, you would assume that these two properties are the same:
`this.style.background`
`this.style.background-color`

But, depending on the browser, you could be wrong or right. IE especially is inconsistent, and frequently changes to `this.style.background` do not affect `background-color` at all, so setting `background:red;` does not mean `background-color` is red. It also does not mean that `background-color` is equal to `rgb(255,0,0)`, or `red`, or `#ff0000`. Its' extremely unpredictable.

In order to make this game work, you would need to do something called **normalizing**. This means you would write a function able to handle `red`, `#ff0000`, `#f00`, `rgba(255,0,0)`, `rgba(255,0,0,1)` and `rgb( 255   ,   0 ,0)` and turn that into one specific format that can then be compared correctly.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about the format of the rgb specifications.